# How can I make a Map[ (Int,Int) , List[Int] ] that spans from (0,0) to (8,8)?

Tags: scala

I am working on a scala program that is essentially a sudoku solver, and in order to test it I need to make an "empty" map that includes every coordinate of a sudoku board (0,0),(0,1),(0,2) etc all the way up until (8,8), which represent the 81 cells in a sudoku board. The List[Int] in the map represents the possible values that can be placed at that cell. So, I need to make a map that has all of these coordinates mapped to a List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) to indicate that every value can be placed at every cell.

How would I do this? I have tried tinkering with the to function ( 0.to(9)) but I cannot get it to work

Comment: Please, insert the code you have tried, even if it doesn't work, so people can help you based on it.

Comment: Seems like your data type `Map[(Int, Int), List[Int]]` is more complex than it needs to be. Another way to solve this problem might be to simplify this type.

Comment: A map with all coordinate combinations seems like it should instead be a two-dimensional array. I can't think of anything in Sudoku solving that would be easier if it were a Map.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're going about this all wrong, but what do I know?

```
val grid = (for {
  x <- 0 to 8
  y <- 0 to 8
} yield (x,y) -> (1 to 9).toList).toMap
```